# Не работает estimatedRowHeight и UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Tags: ios, swift

Исходник сэнсэя по урокам которого я учусь:
designcode.io/cloud/Chapter3Part2-Swift2/11-TableViewClass.zip 
Мой исходник:
github.com/gemcave/dn-ios-design-study
[image: Скрин симулятора]
[image: Настройки ячейки]
У сэнсэя работает estimatedRowHeight и UITableViewAutomaticDimension, у меня нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В примере, который вы используете есть две кнопки, которых нет у вас - лайки и комменты. сами кнопки не важны, но они добавляют несколько констрейнтов, которые дают ios понять как располагать элементы. В вашем случае констрейнтов недостаточно, поэтому, когда вы запускаетесь, размер ячейки стновится 44(default), при этом в консоли появляется такое сообщение:

> Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest > a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering > the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

чтобы это исправить достаточно добавить констрейнт между низом ячейки и низом `Author`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал использовать

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

И высчитывать высоту каждой ячейки динамически. Я использую вот такую функцию:

```
    static func sizeLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGRect{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGFloat.max))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame
}
```